# React with Semantic TextArea not updating value when props updated

Tags: reactjs, textarea, semantic-ui-react

I've this class which is a specific entry in a list.
I am trying to use the semantic-ui-react TextArea as a controlled component.
When an external event (changing the selected language) triggers the componentWillReceiveProps method, my data object in state is updated with the new data.
However the rendered value of the TextArea, which is set to this.state.value, is never changed.
I've verified that the state is in fact the new value, but I do not understand why the rendered value does not change.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Segment, Grid, Button, TextArea, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const UNAVAILABLE = "Translation unavailable."

class Key extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: props.data[props.language]
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps = (props) => {
        this.setState({
            data: props.data[props.language]
        })
    }

    handleEdit = (event) => {
        this.setState({data: event.target.value})
        this.props.edit(event.target.value)
    }

    render = () => {
        let inverted = null;
        let color = null;
        if(this.props.hasChanged()){
            inverted = true;
            color = 'green'
        } else if(!this.props.data[this.props.language]) {
            inverted = true;
            color = 'red'
        }

        return(
            <Segment className='key' inverted={inverted} color={color}>
                <Grid columns='equal' textAlign='left'>
                    <Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column className='keyField' width={3}>
                            {this.props.name}
                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column width={5}>
                            {this.props.data.en}
                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column width={5}>
                            <Form>
                                <TextArea
                                    value={this.state.data} 
                                    placeholder={UNAVAILABLE}
                                    onChange={this.handleEdit}>
                                </TextArea>
                            </Form>
                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column>
                            <Button
                                className='button'
                                floated='right' 
                                icon='trash alternate' 
                                compact
                                onClick={this.props.delete}
                            />
                        </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid.Row>
                </Grid>
            </Segment>
        )
    }
}

export default Key;
```

SOLUTION: The real problem was my data object has values of data[language] that end up being undefined. I was expecting it to take a null value and go back to the placeholder, but apparently when you give null to the value field of a textArea that has a value it does nothing, as shown in github.com/facebook/react/issues/2533. Adding a check whether the property was in the data object and using an empty string instead fixed my issue.

Comment: DANGER : do not directely set the state in componentWillReceive . use some conditional statements... it will crash your app...

Comment: please do `console.log(this.state.data)` above return and check if data is updating in state or not.or please add a codepen example

Comment: Fair point, will add that to my code, should not change why this isn't working though I think

Comment: @akshay I have done that and can confirm the state has been changed

Comment: @AlexCournoyer I can confirm on changing props TextArea value will is changing as I have replicated your code on my local and its working fine.

Comment: @akshay can I get a copy of your code just in case it's something super obvious that I missed like a typo or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify its working for me

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Segment, Grid, Button, TextArea, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class AboutPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      data:"initial data"
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({data: 'new Data'})
    }, 5000)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>About</h1>

        <Key data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



const UNAVAILABLE = "Translation unavailable."

class Key extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: props.data
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps = (props) => {
        this.setState({
            data: props.data
        })
    }

    handleEdit = (event) => {
        this.setState({data: event.target.value})
        // this.props.edit(event.target.value)
    }

    render = () => {
        let inverted = null;
        let color = null;
        if(true){
            inverted = true;
            color = 'green'
        } else if(!this.props.data[this.props.language]) {
            inverted = true;
            color = 'red'
        }

        return(
            <Segment className='key' inverted={inverted} color={color}>
                <Grid columns='equal' textAlign='left'>
                    <Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column className='keyField' width={3}>
                            {'name'}
                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column width={5}>
                            {'English'}
                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column width={5}>
                            <Form>
                                <TextArea
                                    value={this.state.data} 
                                    placeholder={UNAVAILABLE}
                                    onChange={this.handleEdit}>
                                </TextArea>
                            </Form>
                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column>
                            <Button
                                className='button'
                                floated='right' 
                                icon='trash alternate' 
                                compact
                            />
                        </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid.Row>
                </Grid>
            </Segment>
        )
    }
}

export default AboutPage;
```

Comment: Yup, that definitely works, now I just have to figure out why mine doesn't.

Comment: you should check props in componentWillReceiveProps also console.log state in render to verify state is updating.

Comment: I'm still trying to fix mine but I will definitely accept this if I get it working

Comment: The real problem was my data object has values of data[language] that end up being undefined, I was expecting it to take a null value and go back to the placeholder, but apparently when you give null to the value field of a textArea that has a value it does nothing, as shown in https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2533. Adding a check whether the property was in the data object and using an empty string instead fixed my issue.